# How do i publish my Visual Studio Project to Github

Tags: github

I have made a project in Visual Studio that I would like to share with people on Github.

Searching Google and here, i can not seem to find a simple guide for how I get this project uploaded to to Github.

I have Git Extensions installed, i have some application from Github installed as well. I simply cant figure out what i need to do to share my project on Github. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `git init; git remote add; git push`. VS needn't have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found this  [Extension](https://visualstudio.github.com/) to VS15:

Answer (score 1):

Use this easy tool:
https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

No Cygwin needed

Answer (score 0):

I have always found [**this guide**](http://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git)
to be quite helpful.

I am using Cygwin with the Git package installed. Once that is done you need to
[**set up**](http://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) SSH keys.
This is essentially a key that is stored in a file on your computer. You enter
the same key into the "SSH Keys" page on GitHub, and as long as that file with
the key is found you can push and pull from GitHub.